I got next js docker error from getServerSideProps: connect ECONNREFUSED 172.25.0.2:8080
I have separate docker-compose.yaml file. One is for backend and it's database, nginx, and node etc. Other one is for my next js frontend.
FRONTEND:

services:
  bsb_front:
    image: bsb_front
    container_name: bsb_front
    build:
      context: .
      target: dev
    restart: always
    command: yarn dev
    environment:
      - NODE_ENV=development
      - BASE_URL=http://localhost:8080
      - BASE_URL_TEST=http://localhost:8080
    volumes:
      - .:/app
      - /app/node_modules
      - /app/.next
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    networks:
      - bsb-network
networks:
  bsb-network:
    name: bsb-network
    external: true

BACKEND:
version: "3.4"

services:
    bsb_php:
        container_name: bsb_php
        image: bsb_php
        build:
            dockerfile: docker/php/Dockerfile
            target: sylius_php
        depends_on:
            - bsb_database
        env_file:
            - .env.local
        environment:
            - PHP_DATE_TIMEZONE=${PHP_DATE_TIMEZONE:-UTC}
        networks:
            - backend
        volumes:
            - .:/srv/sylius:rw,cached
            - ./public:/srv/sylius/public:rw,delegated
            - public-media:/srv/sylius/public/media:rw

    bsb_database:
        container_name: bsb_database
        image: mysql:8.0.36
        networks:
            - backend
        env_file:
            - docker/mysql/.env
        volumes:
            - ./docker/mysql/data:/var/lib/mysql:rw
        ports:
            - "3306:3306"
        cap_add:
            - SYS_NICE #

    bsb_node:
        image: bsb_node
        container_name: bsb_node
        build:
            dockerfile: docker/nodejs/Dockerfile
        depends_on:
            - bsb_php
        environment:
            - GULP_ENV=dev
            - PHP_HOST=bsb_php
            - PHP_PORT=9000
        networks:
            - backend
        volumes:
            - ./public:/srv/sylius/public:rw,delegated
        ports:
            - "35729:35729"

    bsb_nginx:
        image: bsb_nginx
        container_name: bsb_nginx
        build:
            dockerfile: docker/nginx/dev/Dockerfile
        networks:
            - bsb-network
            - backend
        depends_on:
            - bsb_php
            - bsb_node
        volumes:
            - ./public:/srv/sylius/public:ro
            - public-media:/srv/sylius/public/media:ro,nocopy
        ports:
            - "8080:80"

volumes:
    mysql-data:
    public-media:

networks:
    backend:
        name: backend
        external: false
    bsb-network:
        external: true


I do have a public and server runtime config in my next.config.js
//.env.development
NEXT_SERVER_API_URL="http://bsb_nginx:8080"
NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL=http://localhost:8080

//next.config.js
serverRuntimeConfig: {
   apiUrl: process.env.NEXT_SERVER_API_URL,
},
publicRuntimeConfig: {
   apiUrl: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL,
}

// api base url
import getConfig from "next/config";

export const getBaseUrl = () => {
  const { serverRuntimeConfig, publicRuntimeConfig } = getConfig();

  const apiUrl =
    (serverRuntimeConfig.apiUrl as string) ||
    (publicRuntimeConfig.apiUrl as string);

  return apiUrl;
};



But still i got error Error: {"duration":76,"problem":"CONNECTION_ERROR","originalError":{"message":"connect ECONNREFUSED 172.25.0.2:8080","name":"Error","stack":"Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 172.25.0.2:8080\n    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1555:16)","config":{"url":"shop-api/products/by-code/APPL-MTV03ZP","method":"get","headers":{"Accept":"application/ld+json, application/json","Content-Type":"application/json","User-Agent":"axios/0.21.4"},"params":{},"baseURL":"http://bsb_nginx:8080","transformRequest":[null],"transformResponse":[null],"timeout":50000,"xsrfCookieName":"XSRF-TOKEN","xsrfHeaderName":"X-XSRF-TOKEN","maxContentLength":-1,"maxBodyLength":-1,"transitional":{"silentJSONParsing":true,"forcedJSONParsing":true,"clarifyTimeoutError":false}},"code":"ECONNREFUSED"},"ok":false,"status":null,"headers":null,"config":{"url":"shop-api/products/by-code/APPL-MTV03ZP","method":"get","headers":{"Accept":"application/ld+json, application/json","Content-Type":"application/json","User-Agent":"axios/0.21.4"},"params":{},"baseURL":"http://bsb_nginx:8080","transformRequest":[null],"transformResponse":[null],"timeout":50000,"xsrfCookieName":"XSRF-TOKEN","xsrfHeaderName":"X-XSRF-TOKEN","maxContentLength":-1,"maxBodyLength":-1,"transitional":{"silentJSONParsing":true,"forcedJSONParsing":true,"clarifyTimeoutError":false}},"data":null}


If you are trying to connect from one container to another, then NEXT_SERVER_API_URL is wrong.
NEXT_SERVER_API_URL="http://bsb_nginx:8080"

bsb_nginx is the correct hostname, yes, but port 8080 is the published port visible to your host machine, not the one visible to other containers.
    bsb_nginx:
        image: bsb_nginx
        container_name: bsb_nginx
        ...
        ports:
            - "8080:80"

So "http://bsb_nginx:80" or just "http://bsb_nginx" should be correct.
